# How to get a count from hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a question about hashmap, 
I have a class product:

```
public class product{
    private String libele;
```

and also a class special product:

```
public class SpecialProd extends Product{   
       private HashMap<Product, Price> comp = new HashMap<Product, Price>();
        public HashMap<Product, Price> getComp() {
            return comp;
        }
}
```

The problem is that i need to know how much products i have in stock, the total amount of the products and how much for every product:
so i used this code in the class storage:

```
public class Storage{

   private  HashMap<Product, Price> port = new HashMap<Product, Price>();
public void total (){
        int nombre=0;
        int total = 0;
        int i=0;
        for (Product p:port.keySet()){
            if (port.containsKey(a)){
               // ++nombre; 
            }


        total = port.size();
        System.out.println(+nombre+ "of" +a.getLibele());
        }

        System.out.println("total products:" +total);


}


  // this is an intern class
  static class Part{
        private int price;

        public Price(int price) {
            this.price= price;
        }



        public int getprice() {
            return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(int price) {
            this.price= price;
        }


                }




   }
```

i couldn't get the count of every product and the total prices.

Any ideas please?

Comment: That's probably because you didn't do anything to get any prices, or populated it in the first place. You are just getting the number of keys in your hash table. Along with this that code will not run, some of your variables you never defined (ex: `a`).

Comment: the getPrice's method doesn't do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try enumerating the HashMap and get the desired values.

```
 int count=0;
 for(p : port.keySet()){
 count ++;
 price = price + port.get(a);
 }
```

Comment: i can't use port.keyset() because the keys are products.

Comment: Then maybe you can try  `while(port.containsKey()){// value evaluation } `

Comment: public void prix() {
      int count=0;
      int Price=0;
      while(port.containsKey(Price)) {
       co ++;
       Price= Price+ port.get(Price);
      }
     
    }

The operator + is undefined for arguments type int in storage.price

Comment: no, i mentionned the error there:
The operator + is undefined for arguments type int in storage.price

Comment: Then you must be using some integer/float (any numeric) data type to store the Price value in the Price class. Use price._val_ .

Comment: class Price{
        private int price;

That's right i'm using and int storage but prince.val doesn't work on the code.

Comment: By _val_  I meant the variable you are storing your value in (in the class Price.) But make sure it's accessible.

Comment: yes, that's what i've done but its not working because i can't use Price.*

Comment: Because you have declared the variable private!

Comment: I see, I think I will restart the code from the beginning.